# Paypal MPL approval process

Tags: ios, paypal

All,
I'm just building my first IOS Paypal enabled application. I've followed all the steps and actually my application works, I got my production ID without really submitting my application to paypal, As soon as I hit submit, it gave me the production id and said application automatically approved!

Can I go ahead and submit my application to apple or I'm supposed to do something else?!

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been approved and you have your live ID then you should be ready to rock.  You might want to run a basic API call with the live ID on the live servers just to ensure everything is working as you expect.  Once you're satisfied with that then you're ready to submit to Apple.